# Is it illegal to publish a website anonymously/pseudonymously in Germany?

Tags: germany, privacy

Occasionally on websites you see a link labeled "Impressum", and on clicking it it invariably shows a German-looking name and contact information in Germany. [Looking "Impressum" up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Impressum&oldid=554411373#Webpages), I was surprised to find a claim that publishers of websites are required by law to provide their real name and contact information:

> The Telemediengesetz ("Telemedia Act") requires that German websites must disclose information about the publisher, including their name and address, telephone number or e-mail address, trade registry number, VAT number, and other information depending on the type of company. German websites are defined as being published by individuals or organisations that are based in Germany, so an Impressum is required regardless of whether a site is in the .de domain.
>
> This law has created privacy concerns for individuals who maintain blogs or personal homepages. The law has also caused lawyers to scrutinise websites for this information and send cease-and-desist letters to their maintainers in case it is missing.

Is it really illegal to publish a website anonymously/pseudonymously in Germany? If so, what is the reasoning behind this requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Following the internal link in that Wiki article, we land on the German Wiki page for the relevant law, the *Telemediengesetz*. I have not been able to find an official or semi-official English translation of that law on the Web.

In the Wiki article, it says that the requirements regarding the *Impressum* were relaxed in 2009 when the law was re-enacted in revised form. In particular, Section 5 "Informationspflichten" (~ Duties to Provide Information):

> <sub>(1) Diensteanbieter haben für geschäftsmäßige, in der Regel gegen
>   Entgelt angebotene Telemedien folgende Informationen leicht erkennbar,
>   unmittelbar erreichbar und ständig verfügbar zu halten:</sub>
>
> <sub>1. den Namen und die Anschrift, unter der sie niedergelassen
>   sind, bei juristischen Personen zusätzlich die Rechtsform, den
>   Vertretungsberechtigten und, sofern Angaben über das Kapital der
>   Gesellschaft gemacht werden, das Stamm- oder Grundkapital sowie, wenn
>   nicht alle in Geld zu leistenden Einlagen eingezahlt sind, der
>   Gesamtbetrag der ausstehenden Einlagen,</sub>
>
> <sub>2. Angaben, die eine schnelle elektronische Kontaktaufnahme und
>   unmittelbare Kommunikation mit ihnen ermöglichen, einschließlich der
>   Adresse der elektronischen Post,</sub>
>
> <sub>3. soweit der Dienst im Rahmen einer Tätigkeit angeboten oder
>   erbracht wird, die der behördlichen Zulassung bedarf, Angaben zur
>   zuständigen Aufsichtsbehörde,</sub>
>
> <sub>4. das Handelsregister, Vereinsregister, Partnerschaftsregister
>   oder Genossenschaftsregister, in das sie eingetragen sind, und die
>   entsprechende Registernummer,</sub>
>
> <sub>5. soweit der Dienst in Ausübung eines Berufs im Sinne von
>   Artikel 1 Buchstabe d der Richtlinie 89/48/EWG des Rates vom 21.
>   Dezember 1988 über eine allgemeine Regelung zur Anerkennung der
>   Hochschuldiplome, die eine mindestens dreijährige Berufsausbildung
>   abschließen (ABl. EG Nr. L 19 S. 16), oder im Sinne von Artikel 1
>   Buchstabe f der Richtlinie 92/51/EWG des Rates vom 18. Juni 1992 über
>   eine zweite allgemeine Regelung zur Anerkennung beruflicher
>   Befähigungsnachweise in Ergänzung zur Richtlinie 89/48/EWG (ABl. EG
>   Nr. L 209 S. 25, 1995 Nr. L 17 S. 20), zuletzt geändert durch die
>   Richtlinie 97/38/EG der Kommission vom 20. Juni 1997 (ABl. EG Nr. L
>   184 S. 31), angeboten oder erbracht wird, Angaben über</sub>
>
> <sub>a) die Kammer, welcher die Diensteanbieter angehören,</sub>
>
> <sub>b) die gesetzliche Berufsbezeichnung und den Staat, in dem die
>   Berufsbezeichnung verliehen worden ist,</sub>
>
> <sub>c) die Bezeichnung der berufsrechtlichen Regelungen und dazu, wie
>   diese zugänglich sind,</sub>
>
> <sub>6. in Fällen, in denen sie eine Umsatzsteueridentifikationsnummer
>   nach § 27a des Umsatzsteuergesetzes oder eine
>   Wirtschafts-Identifikationsnummer nach § 139c der Abgabenordnung
>   besitzen, die Angabe dieser Nummer,</sub>
>
> <sub>7. bei Aktiengesellschaften, Kommanditgesellschaften auf Aktien
>   und Gesellschaften mit beschränkter Haftung, die sich in Abwicklung
>   oder Liquidation befinden, die Angabe hierüber.</sub>
>
> <sub>(2) Weitergehende Informationspflichten nach anderen
>   Rechtsvorschriften bleiben unberührt.</sub>

What this Section 5 says is that yes, service providers (and a blogger could be a "service provider" under this law) have all sorts of obligations to conspicuously identify who they are, what they do, et cetera. However, the key words here are *... geschäftsmäßige,  in der Regel gegen Entgelt angebotene Telemedien ...*.

For the purposes of this discussion, we may translate this passage thus, keeping in mind that a blog, like any website, can be considered a "telemedium":

> ... commercial telemedia ordinarily offered in exchange
>   for valuable consideration ... .

So if your blog is **not** commercial and for-pay, Section 5 with its duties to provide information does not apply to you.

Before you heave a sigh of relief, keep in mind that German telecommunications and libel laws are not the most liberal when it comes to free speech and protection against attempts to impede freedom of expression.

There are numerous cases in which German bloggers have been dragged into court over content on their blogs, even third-party comments left by anonymous commenters, that someone found injurious to their reputation. The time and expense required to defend against such litigation can be considerable.

Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and the foregoing is not legal advice. Consult with an attorney if you have legal questions and anything is at stake for you.

Comment: [English translation of Telemediengesetz (PDF)](http://www.cgerli.org/fileadmin/user_upload/interne_Dokumente/Legislation/Telemedia_Act__TMA_.pdf). I'm not entirely sure for the translation's accuracy, but the source ([Centre for German Legal Information](http://www.cgerli.org/)) seems legit.

Comment: @Yannis Yes, good find. Haven't looked at that translation closely but what I have seen looks good!

Comment: Left unsaid in my Answer was that while a hobbyist blogger should be within their rights publishing anonymously or pseudonymously, she or he can still be sued (copyright / file-sharing) or prosecuted (libel / incitement /...) based on a request to the ISP to disclose the blogger's data, a request which must be complied with. Then again, it is implied. Hard to say how much info is too much, or too little.

Comment: Bear in mind that "geschäftsmäßig" should not be translated as "commercial", but as "business-like". Merely regularly updating the site is sometimes seen as sufficient to fulfil this restriction, so it is not quite true that "if your blog is not commercial and for-pay", the blog would be exempt.